# Update MBR of new drive after cloning

Tags: backup, bootloader, dd

I just cloned the Linux partition of my laptop to be used on the desktop.

However, this was just a straight DD execution, and the MBR of the new drive is not affected.  How can I change the new drive to be bootable?

The exact DD command I used was `dd if=/dev/sda5 of=/dev/sdc5`

Comment: Using `dd` to copy a partition could, I suppose be done. But it involves tedious details which I would never want to mess with unless I had **no other** choice. Why not boot the Ubuntu Live CD or USB and use `gparted` to copy the partition? That way the partition table in the MBR will be properly updated as well as any other file system parameters that might need to be "tweaked" as a result of the relocation.

Comment: Please include exact `dd` command line used in question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that :

- Your destination partition table is correctly defined
- Sizes of `sda5` and `sdc5` matches (otherwise it would not make sense, or you will need to run `gparted` to resize the *filesystem* if `sda5` is smaller than `sdc5`)

You will probably want to copy just the first 440 bytes of the MBR since the partition table is whithin the MBR sector (see wikipedia entries [(en)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) or [(fr)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) with `dd` command examples).

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdc bs=1 count=440
```

Anyway, `gparted` allows you to easily and quickly copy data between partitions since it analyzes filesystems and only copies the bytes needed, so I would recommend gparted against `dd`.

The only exception would be in the case you want to recover a broken drive, in that case I would recommend you to extract data with `dd_rescue` which is more resilient to errors than `dd`, probably faster, too.